# API route no funciona luego de agregar middleware

Tags: laravel, api

Error del servidor 500:

> POST http://localhost/onesignal/public/api/v1/sessiondata2 500 (Internal Server Error)

La ruta y el controlador funcionan a la perfección sin middleware (Aunque este esté sin lógica extra)

```
Route::post('sessiondata2', 'sessionController@consularSessionYActividad')->middleware('isjson');
```

Middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class isjson
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request);
}
}
```

Los middleware en rutas web funcionan bien, que es lo diferente con las rutas api?

Tambien intenté agregar el middleware agrupando rutas pero me da el mismo error.

Comment: agregaste tu middleware en el archivo `Kernel.php`?

Comment: Me equivoqué y lo tenia agregado en protected $middleware cuando en realidad van protected $routeMiddleware, Error de capa 8, Gracias!